# grouping motion vectors

Tags: c, opencv, k-means, opticalflow

I am using -Lucas-kanade algorithm to calculate the optical flow of a video sequences with openCV. I got the motion vectors. Now I want to group those motion vectors in some clusters.
the vectors which are near by each other I want to group them together. Some thing like nearest neighbor approach. But I don't know how I can implement the same. any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

I used cvKMeans2() to group the corner points after running the optical flow algorithm...

I have the clusters in a vector of vectors clustercontainer. Now I want to draw a boundary line around every clusters..I am not sure how can I do so...if anybody knows please help.

Using the below code from openCV manual I draw the circle around every cluster..but I want to draw rectangle rather than a  circle..any body please help me.

```
    for(int h = 0; h < clusterContainer.size(); h++ )
        {

           CvPoint pt1,pt2;
               CvMat box[100];

           pt1.x=(int)points->data.fl[h*2];
           pt1.y=(int)points->data.fl[h*2+1];
              cvCircle( frame1, pt1, 20, CV_RGB(255,255,0),4);

}
```

[image]

Comment: What type of grouping are you looking for? Do you want to group vectors which point in the same direction/are close to each other/resemble distinct moving objects?

Comment: yes you  are right..I want to group the vectors have same direction and close to each other...But don't have any idea how to do so..can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide some example images, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have attached the o/p of one frame of the video sequences I used..it shows the motion vectors generated from the previous frame.

Comment: Dear Chris,

Right I used cvKMeans2(..) to cluster the features and got the center points of the clusters..but the problem is when i am trying to show the centers using cvShow() in my current frame it is not showing any result.

Comment: Using KMeans will cluster points which are close together, but won't take any motion into consideration, so your optical flow evaluation is probably not being used. Is the camera moving? If the camera is stationary then you could filter points by the distance they move between frames, and then run KMeans to cluster points on the same object? Or use a more traditional background subtraction type system to find moving silhouettes?

Comment: yes the camera is also moving so I also  cannot do background subtraction.

Comment: Hi there, Did you manage to Get to the correct answer? I see below you said you used KMEAN algorithm to group the motion vector which have similar direction and magnitude, any chance you'd be able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used KMEAN algorithm to group the motion vector which hvae similar direction and magnitude.

Comment: How did you do this? I have been trying to also group motion vectors using direction and Magnitude but have not been able to find what input parameters to use? I have an array of 4 columns: [xposition, yposition, dx, dy]. What format would i need to have my array in to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the bounding rectangle from a set of points, you can use the OpenCV [boundingRect()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) function. Also note the similar [fitEllipse()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitellipse) function.

**boundingRect**
*Calculates the up-right bounding rectangle of a point set.*

```
C++: Rect boundingRect(InputArray points)  
Python: cv2.boundingRect(points) → retval
C: CvRect cvBoundingRect(CvArr* points, int update=0 )
Python: cv.BoundingRect(points, update=0) → CvRect
```

Parameters: points – Input 2D point set, stored in std::vector or Mat.
The function calculates and returns the minimal up-right bounding rectangle for the specified point set.

**fitEllipse**
*Fits an ellipse around a set of 2D points.*

```
C++: RotatedRect fitEllipse(InputArray points)
Python: cv2.fitEllipse(points) → retval
C: CvBox2D cvFitEllipse2(const CvArr* points)
Python: cv.FitEllipse2(points) → Box2D
```

Parameters: points – Input 2D point set, stored in:

```
std::vector<> or Mat (C++ interface)
CvSeq* or CvMat* (C interface)
Nx2 numpy array (Python interface)
```

The function calculates the ellipse that fits (in a least-squares sense) a set of 2D points best of all. It returns the rotated rectangle in which the ellipse is inscribed. The algorithm [Fitzgibbon95] is used.

Comment: yes you are right , I have already tried bounding rec, but now the problem is one object may contain more than one object. As you can see in the above output one car has several circles. Thank you any way.

Comment: What is the desired output? Merging the overlapping objects? If you have one point describing each circle in your image (for example the centre) you could check if the distance between centres fell below some threshold (such as the current radius), if two circles are this close then you could define a new circle at their average position, expand the radius for the new point and remove the original points.

Comment: the desire output is to detect moving object. I also tried your idea, the problem is, if two or more car is close to each other then they merge all the circles together and shows as a single object

Comment: Yep, I guess that comes down to your method of how do you detect a vehicle. From the image is seems you are detecting some of the front/rear lights of the cars when you want to detect the whole car which consists of two (red or white) lights (at night anyway...). There are many papers on vehicle detection, especially in terms of driver assistance, but this topic is too big to discuss in an already off-topic comment thread!

Comment: Thank you Chris for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample image, why would you want to group vectors that have the same direction and are close to each other?
Remember, vectors pointing towards the travel direction, in 2D, in the image all have different angles/directions.

I suggest that you group together all vectors that point more or less at the same image points.

Comment: I need to group the motion vector to track any moving object in the next frame.

Comment: I guess you should mention that in your post.   
Also, you must compensate for the ego-motion (self motion) before you can detect other motions.

Comment: Dear future flagger--"ego-motion" is a technical term, not a rude comment.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egomotion